# How to get text's coordinate inside a TextView?

Tags: android

I have a situation:There are two TextViews, one's gravity is left|centerVertical and the other's is right|centerVertical. when wraping them, the texts must look like they wrap their positions exactly, left to left ,right to right. To achive this, I have to get the coordinate of text inside TextView, so that I can calculate the offset, how to get text's coordinate inside TextView without inner padding?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no solution to get text's coordinate inside a TextView without inner padding value.

If you want to get text's coordinate, you should calculate using view's location and inner padding value.

```
public float getTextPositionX(TextView textView) {
    return textView.getX() + textView.getPaddingLeft();
}

public float getTextPositionY(TextView textView) {
    return textView.getY() + textView.getPaddingTop();
}
```